# Site URL displays "Page Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server." but the backend loads fine

Tags: install, apache

I've recently installed Craft on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 12.04 droplet. After finally getting all the permissions set and everything set up I get "Page Not Found. The Requested URL was not found on this server." when I visit the site URL but the admin area loads just fine.

Anybody have an idea of what could be going on? Or maybe a way to debug it? I've checked the Apache and PHP error logs (I think) but they don't show anything strange.

I've also tried a brand new install but also had no luck. I'm guessing it's Apache related but I'm not an apache expert.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does anything work if you add index.php to the url (www.mysite.com/index.php/yourpageslug)?

Comment: Is it a Craft styled 404 or an Apache one?

Comment: It's a craft styled 404 and index.php doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! Not really sure exactly what was causing it, but it seems to have had something to do with my Capistrano setup not craft or Apache.